# Checking that checkbox is checked before going to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a thumbnail picture that when clicked, links to another page. And I want to make sure that the user has checked a check box before the user can click on the thumbnail picture to go to the other page.

My Javascript function is currently:

```
function CheckForm(obj1) { 

if (obj1.accept.checked == false){
  alert ("You must check the box to confirm you have read and accept the Terms.");
return false;
} 
return true;
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<input name="accept" type="checkbox" value="0">Confirmation Box</input>

<a href="http://somelink.com">
<img src="/Koala.jpg" height="94" width="94" />
</a>
```

So I want the user to have to check the checkbox before he/she is able to click on the koala.jpg thumbnail. So the only way the user can go to the somelink.com is if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="http://somelink.com" onclick="return CheckForm()">


function CheckForm(obj1) { 

if (!($('#accept').is(":checked"))){
  alert ("You must check the box to confirm you have read and accept the Terms.");
return false;
} 
return true;
}
```

Comment: same as AKnox , you put jquery in the tags , so I'm using jquery in the answer

Comment: Might want to fix `onlcick`

Comment: Wait, nvm. Not working, whenever I have the checkbox checked, the alert still pops up...

Comment: Any ideas as to why even when the checkbox is checked the alert still pops up and wont let me go to the link?

Comment: @DBroncos1558 the name of the checkbox has to be exactly ('#accept')

Comment: @DBroncos1558 look here to see more http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: ahh thank you for that link! I changed where you put #accept, to :checkbox ... your a life saver! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

the question has jquery listed in the tags so i'm assuming you have access to that library:

```
jQuery('#name').is(':checked') == false
```